# what is the value of if/unless modifier?

Tags: ruby

I could not find anywhere a formal specification of the `if` (or `unless`) modifier:

```
123 if x > 0
```

what is the value of the above statement if `x` is not above zero? `irb` suggests `nil`, but is it documented anywhere?

(yes, this is perhaps a stupid question, sorry, could not find a spec).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is `nil`. What else could it return? The statement in the `if` clause is used for the if itself, and the `then` statement is not executed. There is nothing to return, so `nil`.

[Relevant spec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb#L96-L101)

```
it "returns nil if else-body is empty and expression is false" do
  if false
    123
  else
  end.should == nil
end
```

Comment: it can return the value of the expression that `if` checks

Comment: @akonsu That would be reusing data in an unexpected way imo.

Comment: @akonsu: that would be a huge surprise for most people. Why do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I am not saying that it is a good idea, I am saying, since Tass asked what else could it return, that it is not at all obvious what it should return.

Answer (score 5):

An expression that is not evaluated is the same as not existing. And your condition should be part of some code block such as definition or the main environment, etc. A code block without a content is evaluated to `nil`.

```
class A; end
# => nil

def foo; end
foo
# => nil

()
# => nil

begin; end
# => nil

eval("")
# => nil
```

So the reason your example returns `nil` has nothing to do with condition itself. It is just due to there being no evaluation.